# Increment different fields based on parameter?

Tags: parameters

I have a method for opportunities that increments a field and I would like it to be dynamic/able to make it increment different fields based on a parameter. How would I go about  accessing this field in my method? In the below example the field parameter would be a string that was either 'field1__c' or 'field2__c'.

```
    Public static void myMethod(String currentId, String field){
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT id, field1__c, field2__c from opportunity where id =:currentId];
         //The line below contains the logic that I want but doesn't actually access the field.
        opp.field ++;
    update opp;
}
```

Comment: Consider using dynamic soql query such as - String query = 'SELECT id, ' +field+ ', from opportunity where Id = :currentId';list<sobject> result = database.query(query);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just trying to increment integer type of fields, you can simply get the object as an sobject and update the field value.

E.g.

```
SObject obj = [SELECT Amount from opportunity where id ='0062a000007FSiZAAW'];
obj.put('Amount', Integer.valueOf(obj.get('Amount')) + 10);
update obj;
```

where Amount will be the fieldName passed as parameter.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Have a happy new year.